# ArcPy: creating new table select column in value B if value in column A = x

Tags: python, field, layer, arcpy

I am new to arcpy and trying create new table from existing table. I want to create table: if `type_1` equals `H` then export the values contained in `comment_1`.

Input layer/attribute table:

```
Number  type_1  value_1   comment_1   type_2    value_1   comment_2
23587   H                   abcdef     xyz                something
13878   P                   sdferw     H                  jldoeroslj
156798  Y                   eiroeow    H                  dfadfsdf
```

Output table:

```
Number  comment_1          comment_2
23587   abcdef
13878                      jldoeroslj
156798                     dfadfsdf
```

I tried the following but the output is not something I am looking for:

```
import arcpy

keepFieldList = ('Number', 'comment_1','comment_2')
Trees = "layername"
fieldInfo=""
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(layername)

for field in fieldList:
    if field.name not in keepFieldList:
        fieldInfo = fieldInfo + field.name + " " + field.name + " HIDDEN;"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("layername", "outputlayer", "", "",
                                  fieldInfo)
```

Comment: ArcPy questions are more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the shapefile and then loop through the rows in that copied file,  deleting the rows that don't meet your condition:

```
import arcpy
input_shp = r'C:\Users\path\whatever.shp'
copy_shp = r'C:\Users\path\myfiltered.shp'
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input_shp, copy_shp)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(copy_shp, 'type_1') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
                if row[0] != 'H':
                    cursor.deleteRow()
```

or another way, if you have to do this for many combos of fields and strings is to use a SQL expression, deleting the rows in the copied file that do not meet your condition:

```
import arcpy
input_shp = r'C:\Users\path\whatever.shp'
copy_shp = r'C:\Users\path\myfiltered.shp'
fieldname = 'type_1'
keepValue = 'H'
sql = fieldname + " <> " + "'" + str(keepValue) + "'"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(copy_shp, fieldname, sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

and lastly, a third way is described [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-rows.htm)

but as @PolyGeo said, the GIS stack exchange forum is much better for GIS questions